# How do I validate data update using react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

How do I validate data update using react-query??

I tried
const {mutate} = useMutation((info) => axios.post(url,info,{type:’form’})

mutate(form.getFieldsValues()) but the rule in the form doesn't work.

I need help!!!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide more info. What error are you getting? What is `getFieldsValues()`? Are you updating the cached data using `queryClient.setQueryData()`?